# Why is 'selected' not showing up?

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know why 'selected' is not showing up in my `<option value="">`?

```
    <p>
        <select name="images" class="dropdown">
            <option value="empty"
            <?php if(isset($_GET['images']) && $_GET['images'] === "empty") {
                echo 'selected';
            } ?>>select an image</option>
            <?php foreach ($images as $key => $image) { ?>
                <option value="<?= $key; ?>"
                <?php
                if (isset($_GET['images']) && $_GET['images'] === $key) { // and true is equal to 1, but not identical
                    echo 'selected';
                } ?>><?= $image; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['images']) && $_GET['images'] == 'empty') { ?>
            <span class="warning">Please select an image</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </p>
```

$images is a list of image filenames with appropriate extensions.
I realized that `selected` is appended to the first option `empty` but not to any of the rest of the `<option>`.

Comment: Is your form method set to GET, and is the images get parameter set to "empty" ?

Comment: try using == instead of ===

Comment: Is it you in the photo? :) ... can you print the value of `$_GET['images']` ie `<?php echo "<!-- images:  $_GET[images] -->"?>` or use `error_log` to check that it has the expected value?

Comment: @urban: Highly doubtful ;-)

Comment: @MajorCaiger Yes, my form is set to GET. What did you mean the get parameter set to "empty"?

Comment: The $_GET superglobal contains the parameters passed by the query string i.e. http://example.com/foo?images=empty would result in $_GET['images'] == 'empty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your keys in $images are numeric, e.g. `1 => 'abc'`. Since $_GET always contains string values, the `===` comparison operator used in `$_GET['images'] === $key` is never true. If you use `==` instead, the numeric value and the number in the string value match and 'selected' will be included.

`===` is true, if both operands have the same type and the same value, for `==` it is sufficient for the operands to have the same values.

Comment: Yes, it's an index array. I tried what you said, but if I set `$_GET['images'] == "$key"`, then when I choose `select an image`, both the `empty` and `value = 1` are selected :(

Comment: I hope that makes sense

Comment: You should not include $key in quotes, `$_GET['images'] == $key` would be correct. If you only change this one line, it works as expected. See https://digital-innovation-lab.de/test.php

Comment: Why didn't you set the first image to a value of 0? And somehow not setting it to 0 works

Comment: Now I incorporated 'select an image' inside the array, and it has a value of 0, and all I have to do is to loop through, which made my life easier now.